# Hoop Strength? Bottle shape easiest to squeeze/collapse

Tags: forces, material-science

I'll start by saying while I enjoy physics, I dont have a physics background.

Hypothetically, if a bottle is mounted inside of another bottle, with an airtight seal, and the outer bottle is squeezed, the pressure is transferred to the inner bottle - I imagine equally at all parts.

If the outer bottle is squeezed hard enough (and the inner bottle is thin enough), the inner bottle will collapse/squeeze in on itself...I'd assume at its weakest point.

My understanding is that "hoop strength" applies from a physics perspective.

**My questions is.**..what shape (if any) of the below bottle shapes is the "weakest" when it comes to hoop strength?

ie. Which shape is most suited to easily squeeze/collapse on itself when pressure is appled?

## 1 (perfectly round), #2 (slightly convex), #3 (slightly concave).  Or is there another bottle shape that would be better?

Thank you for your help!!

[image]

Comment: I think it is called hoop stress.

Answer (score 0):

You want a shape such that suface tension (by which I mean tension along the thin material composing the bottle) maximally directs a perpendicular force (from the pressure) into a tangential force. The material is realtively thick in the tangential direction and can resist more force.

The most effective shape would therefore be spherical.